# Remove attributes not falling in particular range in Weka

Tags: weka

I have data-set with 7070 attributes and 70 instances. I want to remove attributes whose values do not lie in the range[20, 2000] in weka. What filter should I use and how to pass parameters to that filter. Also what cutoff should be used for feature selection while using Pearson correlation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code will do. Use "remove" filter and check numeric stats of each attribute if they fall in range add them to an array and then call remove filter.